# Undefined references: linking libraries when compiling a simple GTK+ 3.0 c-program on windows

Tags: c, compilation, gtk, windows-7-x64, undefined-reference

I downloaded **gtk+-bundle_3.4.2-20130513_win64.zip** from [here](http://www.tarnyko.net/dl/gtk.htm)

I've extracted it on **"C:/gtk3/"**
I've added the directory to **%PATH%** variable;

I copied this hello.c code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}   

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

(the backtickes don't work on my cmd so I copied the command to a text file and made it a simple Makefile)

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
```

output:

```
-mms-bitfields -IC:/gtk3/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/gtk3/include/cairo -IC:/gtk3/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtk3/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/gtk3/include/cairo -IC:/gtk3/include/pixman-1 -IC:/gtk3/include -IC:/gtk3/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtk3/include -IC:/gtk3/include/libpng15 -IC:/gtk3/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/gtk3/include/libpng15 -IC:/gtk3/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtk3/lib/glib-2.0/include
```

and

```
pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
```

outputs

```
-LC:/gtk3/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

then I put the whole command in a Makefile like this

```
gcc hello.c $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
```

I also tried all the orders possible, like:

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) hello.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
```

and

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0) hello.c
```

and

```
gcc hello.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0) $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)
```

and

```
gcc $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0) hello.c $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)
```

in all of the above, When I compile using gcc I get this

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `gtk_application_window_new'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `gtk_window_get_type'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `gtk_window_set_title'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `gtk_window_get_type'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `gtk_window_set_default_size'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show_all'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `gtk_application_new'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `g_application_get_type'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `g_application_run'
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRxa5F2.o:hello.c:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `g_object_unref'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using Windows 7 64bits and cmd

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're using `/` instead of `\ ` in your link args: `-LC:/gtk3/lib` .. try  `-LC:\gtk3\lib`. Same thing with includes:  `-IC:\gtk3\include\gtk-3.0`

Comment: I made all `/` into ` \ ` like this 
`gcc hello.c -mms-bitfields -IC:\gtk3\include\gtk-3.0 -IC:\gtk3\include\cairo -IC:\gtk3\include\pango-1.0 -IC:\gtk3\include\atk-1.0 -IC:\gtk3\include\cairo -IC:\gtk3\include\pixman-1 -IC:\gtk3\include -IC:\gtk3\include\freetype2 -IC:\gtk3\include [...]`
still got the same result

Comment: '/' does not matter. The real problem is that the invocation of `pkg-config` is wrong.

Comment: too old ?
If you think the problem is from the bundle itself, can you please give me an all in one bundle that would run on windows 7 64bit ?

Comment: @RedStar are you sure you tried `--flags` in the command line, and not `--cflags`?

Comment: I only ever tired `--cflags`  (now that you mentioned it `pkg-config --flags gtk+-3.0` returns `unknown option --flags` )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was maybe caused by the compiler or GTK3 packages
Solution: uninstall everything, download MSYS2 and download the needed packages
(you can find how to search and install packages by MSYS on their website)
(website provided in the official download page of GTK3)

then everything worked fine,
thanks anyway